# React-Native: Should I use StyleProp<style> or can i write it without StyleProp?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Normally, I write like this:

```js
interface _props{
  style?: TextStyle,
}
```

But should I add StyleProp ?

```js
interface _props{
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>,
}
```

If yes, why ?

Answer (score 1):

StyleProp is generic so it should be aware of what kind of element you want to apply styles. For example, imagine we have two elements which are View and Text and for sure the styles of these two elements are different. By passing an argument to StyleProp, we are telling it what kind of style we are using.